# Add Packages using TinyTex in R for RMarkdown

Tags: r, tinytex

I am trying to install missing packages for my RMarkdown document to create a PDF report.

The packages i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/rstudio/tinytex-releases/releases) under the tinytex releases, specifically `TinyTeX-v2022.11.tar.gz`

I run the following:

```
tinytex:::install_prebuilt(dir = 'C:/Users/op/Downloads/TinyTeX-v2022.11.tar.gz')
3 File(s) copied
1 File(s) copied
Running fc-cache -v -r
tlmgr.pl: already registered auxtree: C:/Users/op/AppData/Local/Programs/R/R-42~1.1/share/texmf
tlmgr.pl: action conf returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr.pl: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
Warning messages:
1: In file.remove(exist_files(c(dir1, dir2))) :
  cannot remove file 'C:/Users/op/Downloads/TinyTeX-v2022.11.tar.gz', reason 'Permission denied'
2: In extract(pkg, exdir = path.expand(target)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In file.rename(dir2, dir1) :
  cannot rename file 'C:/Users/op/Downloads/TinyTeX' to 'C:/Users/op/Downloads/TinyTeX-v2022.11.tar.gz', reason 'The system cannot find the file specified'
```

I do not have admin rights to the PC so cannot install it into Program Files or root.

Can anyone help me to see what i am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time